# Laravel, crear registro si no existe

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php5

Tengo un proyecto en [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) con una base de datos [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) y otra con [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) para hacer un traspaso de datos de un sistema a otro, los campos de uno a otro són similares pero no iguales por ello hago un script tal como este (pongo el código abreviado):

```
public function readCars():JsonResponse
{
    $count = 0;
    $data = array();

    $sql = 'SELECT * from Cars';

    $cars = DB::connection('mysql_old')->select($sql);

    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        unset($data);
        $data['id'] = $car->car_id;
        $data['enabled'] = $car->active;

        $exists = Car::where('id',$data['id'])->first();

        if ($exists === null) {
            Car::create($data);
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $this->jsonOkResponse($count);
}
```

El código lo que hace es buscar el registro en la `mysql_old` , mirar si existe con la función (`DB::where...`) y si no existe lo inserta.

Mi pregunta es si esta opción no es más óptima con `firstOrCreate`.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si, sería más óptimo y lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
public function readCars():JsonResponse
{
    $count = 0;
    $data = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT * from Cars';

    $cars = DB::connection('mysql_old')->select($sql);

    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        $data = [];
        $data['id'] = $car->car_id;
        $data['enabled'] = $car->active;

        $exists = Car::firstOrCreate([
            'id' => $car->car_id
        ], $data);

        $count++;
    }

    return $this->jsonOkResponse($count);
}
```

Los párametros que recibe el método [`firstOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrCreate) son dos `arreglos`, el primer `arreglo` son los atributos a buscar en la tabla (aquí por ejemplo, solo buscamos un registro en la tabla por el atributo `id`) si lo encuentra te devuelve dicho modelo, si no, usa el segundo párametro que es el arreglo de los valores para el nuevo modelo y lo inserta directamente en la base de datos.

---

También podrías hacerlo con [`firstOrNew`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrNew), donde lo que haría, sería lo mismo, pero en vez de guardarlo directamente en la base de datos simplemente lo instancia para que trabajes con el y posteriormente lo guardes manualmente, ejemplo:

```
public function readCars():JsonResponse
{
    $count = 0;
    $data = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT * from Cars';

    $cars = DB::connection('mysql_old')->select($sql);

    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        $data = [];
        $data['id'] = $car->car_id;
        $data['enabled'] = $car->active;

        // Lo instancia si ya existe en la base de datos
        // o lo instancia desde el arreglo $data
        $exists = Car::firstOrNew([
            'id' => $car->car_id
        ], $data);

        $exists->save();

        $count++;
    }

    return $this->jsonOkResponse($count);
}
```

Comment: En el segundo parámetro no debería enviar sólo `data['enabled']` ? Además `$exists` siempre va a ser diferente de null, por lo que carece de sentido hacer la validación, así se optimizria más el código

Comment: @LeviArista según lo que leo en la documentación, el primer párametro es `$attributes` (los criterios de búsqueda) y el segundo es `$values` (información completa para la creación del módelo si no existe)

Comment: @LeviArista y dejé la validación solo porque el autor al parecer hace uso del `$count`

Comment: parece que para lo primero si tienes razón, sería cuestión de probarlo. Pero para lo otro,  creo que se puede optimizar quitando la validacion y haciendo el count++ de frente, pero claro, tambien esta bien, sólo era una sugerencia, saludos.

Comment: Tienes razón, editaré mi respuesta.